# android app crash when I send push

Tags: java, php, android, json, push-notification

I have an android app in market tested and working yesterday. And since yesterday the code haven't changed so the error must be in payload or device (google services not installed or diferent operating system??)
When I send a push notification, the app in the device crash and I get no error so I'm blind here. 
I'm printing the payload in json and I don't see anything wrong here, but maybe somebody with eyes more acurate can.

```
{"registration_ids":["xxxnumbersletersxxxx"],"data":{"message":"Nuevo contenido disponible!","link":"www.hobbyconsolas.es"}}
```

I also put the payload in php just in case:

```
$data = array( 'message' => 'Nuevo contenido disponible!' , 'link' => $link,);
```

Comment: remove last comma it should be `$data = array( 'message' => 'Nuevo contenido disponible!' , 'link' => $link);`

Comment: what about device logs?

Comment: How can I check the device logs?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally discovered the issue. This is happening only with devices with the new operating system android 5.0 +

Comment: And what is the underlying reason or the fix?